# Spring Boot Upgrade from 2.6.x to 2.7.0

Tags: spring-boot

I have upgraded Spring Boot version from 2.6.9 to 2.7.0 we were getting below error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot find cache Named "cacheName"

pom.xml:

```
   <dependency> 
     <groupid>net.sf.ehcache</>
     <artifactId>ehcache</>
  </dependency>
```

ehcache.xml:

```
     <cache name="cacheName" logging="true" maxelementsinmemory="1000" eternal="false" 
        overflowtodisck="false" timetoidleseconds="300" timetoliveseconds="300" 
     memorystorevictionpolicy="LFU"/>
JAVA Method:

   @Cacheable("cacheName")
     public List getValues(){
     return list;
  }
```

Defined @EnableCaching at below class

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableCachong
public class Application extends SpringBootInitializer{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing any cache configuration in your code snippets.
Is the cache implementation supposed to create the cache automatically?

Your application should declare the cache name like this:

```
spring.cache.cache-names=cacheName
```

Also, [see this issue which might explain the change of behavior](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31125).

Comment: You're a saint. Thanks:)